# Loops through Check Box in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have 20 different checkbox (Named Checkbox 30 to Checkbox 50) that I need to check through. Each checkbox selection needs to be translated into 4 different arrays.

My arrays are as follows:
Graph_1(2,20)
Graph_2(2,20)
Graph_3(3,20)
Graph_4(6,20)

Is there an easy way to do this, currently I am using this code. This way will work but it's not pretty nor concise. I figure there must be a quicker way to do it but can't think of a better method to do this.

```
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box 30").ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then ' Team 1
    Graph_1(1, 1) = 1
    Graph_1(2, 1) = 1
    Graph_2(1, 1) = 1
    Graph_2(2, 1) = 1
    Graph_3(1, 1) = 1
    Graph_3(2, 1) = 1
    Graph_3(3, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(1, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(2, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(3, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(4, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(5, 1) = 1
    Graph_4(6, 1) = 1
End If
```

Checkbox 31 refers to row 2 of each array, 32 to row 3 etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What type of check boxes do you use? `ActiveX` or `Form` type?

Comment: _Checkbox 31 refers to row 2 of each array_ that would make Checkbox 50 array `Graph_1(1, 21)` but it is sized `Graph_1(2,20)`

Comment: What do you mean by "translated"? Is there any logic to choose each array values, related to check boxes suffix? And, as stated above, if you want to have a 2D array with  2 rows and 20 columns, you should declare it as `Dim Graph_1(1 To 2, 1 To 20)`... Or `Dim Graph_1(1, 19)`, but knowing that first row and column element **is zero**.

Comment: @CDP1802 thanks for pointing that out I can't count!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next way. It assumes that you use `Form` check boxes and saying "translate" you need to place 1 for the `CheckBox` name ending in 30, 2 for the one ending in 31 and so on:

```
Sub CheckBoxesLoopHandling()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, chkB As CheckBox, ext As Long
  Dim Graph_1(1 To 2, 1 To 1), Graph_2(1 To 2, 1 To 1)
  Dim Graph_3(1 To 3, 1 To 1), Graph_4(1 To 6, 1 To 1) 'array with a column...
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  For Each chkB In sh.CheckBoxes
        ext = Split(chkB.name)(2)
        If ext >= 30 And ext <= 50 And chkB.Value = 1 Then
            Graph_1(1, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_1(2, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_2(1, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_2(2, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_3(1, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_3(2, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_3(3, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(1, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(2, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(3, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(4, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(5, 1) = ext - 29
            Graph_4(6, 1) = ext - 29
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub CheckBoxesLoopHandling()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, chkB As CheckBox, ext As Long
  Dim Graph_1(1 To 2, 1 To 21), Graph_2(1 To 2, 1 To 21)
  Dim Graph_3(1 To 3, 1 To 21), Graph_4(1 To 6, 1 To 21)
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  For Each chkB In sh.CheckBoxes
        ext = Split(chkB.name)(2)
        If ext >= 30 And ext <= 50 And chkB.Value = 1 Then
            Graph_1(1, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_1(2, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_2(1, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_2(2, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_3(1, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_3(2, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_3(3, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(1, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(2, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(3, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(4, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(5, ext - 29) = 1
            Graph_4(6, ext - 29) = 1
      End If
  Next
End Sub
```

to place 1 in the corresponding array columns...

Depending on the "translate" meaning, about I asked but you did not clarify it...

Comment: @CDP1802 Of course... It looked OK  and somebody took me from my office. I did not tested it, of course. Thanks! Even now, I do not know what that "translate" means, anyhow. I will adapt the code, to have some logic anyhow. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question suggests that you would be well served by working through a tutorial on VBA as it appears that you don't understand how to construct looping structures.

You also appear to be confused about which index refers to rows and which to columns.  I've assumed that when you refer to rows in your question you are referring to dimension 2 of the array.

One point to be aware of is that if you import an x * y range from Excel, the indexing in VBA will be y * x.

For you specific issue the code belw may be a helpful pointer.

```
Dim myCB As Long
    
    For myCB = 0 To 20
        Dim myCBStr As String
        myCBStr = VBA.CStr(30 + myCB)
        
        Dim myRow As Long
        myRow = myCB + 1
        
        If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Check Box " & myCBStr).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then ' Team 1
            Graph_1(1, myRow) = 1
            Graph_1(2, myRow) = 1
            Graph_2(1, myRow) = 1
            Graph_2(2, myRow) = 1
            Graph_3(1, myRow) = 1
            Graph_3(2, myRow) = 1
            Graph_3(3, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(1, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(2, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(3, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(4, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(5, myRow) = 1
            Graph_4(6, myRow) = 1
        End If
    Next
```